# how to search related items into ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models

Actually have this model:

```
class MusicFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")

    def exist_in_playlist(self, playlist_id):
        exist = False
        try:
            mp = PlayList.objects.get(id=playlist_id, items__id=self.id)
            exist = True
        except PlayList.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return exist

class PlayList(models.Model):
    items = ManyToManyField(MusicFile)
```

`MusicFile.exist_in_playlist` returns me if X MusicFile is in Y Playlist.

1. With django do I have the option to write something like `PlayList.items.exist(MusicFile)` ?
2. If not, Is this a good implementation for search if a MusicFile is in the PlayList?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify that like this (exists() was added in 1.2):

```
def exist_in_playlist(self, playlist):
    return self.playlist_set.filter(pk=playlist).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if MusicFile.objects.filter(playlist=playlist_id).count() > 0:
    ...
```

or from the other side

```
if PlayList.objects.filter(musicfile=musicfile_id).count() > 0:
    ...
```

See [documentation about accessing related objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects), and [more examples of making queries using Many to Many relationships](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/).